# Pragmatically likely or not

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> Where do you come?

Is this sentence acceptable to say?

> I come to Dhaka Chawbazar.
>
> Where do you come?

The sentence "Where do you come *from*" is correct but my question is if it is possible to use the sentence without "from" with a different meaning.

Comment: No. It is meaningless.

Comment: A person is arguing with me that it is possible.

Comment: Discussing *coitus interruptus* the question would be *conceivable* (if you'll forgive the pun), but it would be damned impertinent. Is that what your person has in mind?

Comment: You could have "Where do you come?" with elision (words omitted) in response to an earlier statement or question. A: "I come to Dhaka Chawbazar often." B: "*Where* do you come?" (meaning "Where did you say you come often?") As though B can't believe what A said and is asking A to repeat the place. You can have most combinations of words if you try hard enough, but that doesn't mean it's normal or recommended.

Answer (score 1):

> > Where do you come?
>
> Is this sentence acceptable to say?

It is completely unacceptable, but for cultural and not grammatical reasons.

Without the preposition *from*, the question is "in what locations do you come?" which only has sexual and pornographic context and answers. The normal sense of come is always directed to the present location (*here*), so the question doesn't work in any other way.

It's optional to spell this 'dirtier' sense of *come* as *cum*. If the speaker and listener were both strict about that distinction, then the question wouldn't have any meaning at all.

Answer (score -1):

: Hey, what a surprise! Why are you here?

: Nothing like that. I often come here.

: Where do you come (here)?

: Here, in...

Here, where means the destination near the speaker and the listener. I just expressed a situational idea.

The sentence is neither natural nor incorrect, I think.

Comment: It is still meaningless to me.

Comment: Where do you come here? The sentence sounds OK. Only when you remove here does it sound very slitted.

Comment: I agree: it is unnatural. Only someone expressing himself extremely poorly might say it. After someone tells us they often come here, we might ask, 'To this very guest house/phone booth/beach?' or 'To where exactly?' or 'And where do you lodge?' It wouldn't enter our heads to ask 'Where do you come?', with or without the 'here'.

Comment: Where do you come (here)? = To where exactly?